# Set Bits of a Byte by a ByteValue

Tags: c#, .net, bit

I have a `Byte scaleValue` with the value 3 (0000.0011 binary)

Now I want to set the BIT 3 and 4 (Scale) of the `Byte Config` (see image) with help of my `Byte scaleValue` but it does not work.

- Before: 0000.0000  (if configByte has the init value 0)
- After:  0001.1000

Here is my code:

```
configByte = (byte) (configByte | (scaleValue << 3));
```

---

Byte Config:
[image]

Comment: If you want to set bits then you should be using or `|`, not and `&`.  What you have will always be 0 because you're anding the 2 with zero bits and whatever bits are set in `scaleValue` will be anded with zero bits of 0x2.

Comment: @juharr Is this now correct?

Comment: It is very urgent. Can somebody help me =/

Comment: Shouldn't you be shifting it 3 to the left instead of 2?

Comment: I've changed 0x02 to 3, but without success

Comment: that can't possibly be your code; a: the assignment is invalid (you'd need to re-cast from `int` to `byte`), and b: you can't declare `configByte` if `configByte` already exists.

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm sorry, I declared configByte to make it clearer on the question, that configByte is type Byte. I adjusted the code.

Comment: @Philies can you define "without success"? What happens, and what did you expect to happen? What makes you think it is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If `configByte` is the entire 8-bit chunk, and `scaleValue` is the value (currently in bits 0/1) that you want to inject into bits 3/4, then fundamentally you need:

```
configByte = (byte)(configByte | (scaleValue << 3));
```

However, this assumes that:

- bits 3/4 in `configByte` are currently zero
- *only* bits 0/1 in `scaleValue` are set (or not)

If those two assumptions aren't true, then you need to mask out the issue with ... masks:

```
configByte = (byte)((configByte & 231) | ((scaleValue & 3) << 3));
```

The `& 231` removes bits 3/4 in the old value. The `& 3` enforces just bits 0/1 in the new value (before the shift)

Answer (score 0):

You can use these extension methods:

```
public static bool GetBit(this byte data, byte position)
{
    byte mask = (byte)(1 << position);
    return (data & mask) != 0;
}
public static byte SetBit(this byte data, byte position, bool value)
{
    byte mask = (byte)(1 << position);

    if (value)
    {
        return (byte)(data | mask);
    }
    else
    {
        return (byte)( data & (~mask));
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte data = 0b0000100;

    if (data.GetBit(2))
    {

    }
    data = data.SetBit(4, true);
    data = data.SetBit(2, false);
}
```